# name of SharedSettings from String

Tags: android, string, sharedpreferences

Please, help with SharedSettings in Android.
How to set value name for SharedSettings from String?
For example, I have value a1d:

```
SharedPreferences values = getSharedPreferences(prefs, 0);
Integer a1d_c = values.getInt("a1d", 1);
```

I need to set value name from string. For example:

```
SharedPreferences values = getSharedPreferences(prefs, 0);
String value_name = "a"+1+"d";
Integer a1d_c = values.getInt(value_name, 1);
```

But 1st and 2nd code make different values.
Thanks.

Comment: I need to make a loop "for" for a1d, a2d, a3d... get this value and if a1d>0 do something. if a2d>0... etc. CODE EXAMPLE - for (i=1; i<10; i++) { String s = "a"+i+"d"; Integer aid_c = values.getInt(s, 1); if (aid_c<0) { // do something }

Comment: There's no reason that your code should fail. I did a quick test and it works for me. What is your expected outcome, and what is actually happening?

Comment: Do you ever set those preferences with values elsewhere in the code?

Comment: Yep. I set those preferences at the first Activity. For test I put first and second code, but at first set default 0 and at second set default 1. If i get int a1d, it equal 0. If I get value using "a"+1+"d" - it equal 1. It different values.

Comment: What exactly isn't working as expected? What should happen, and what does happen instead?

Comment: I need to make a loop with values a1d, a2d with checking equals... At the first Activity i set this preferences. At second activity I make a loop. But if I get pref a1d it != "a"+i+"d". But name "a1d" = "a"+1+"d".

Comment: Is the value that you get back the default value you specified as the second parameter or is it some other value?

Comment: at first start it will be default value (from 1st activity). Value will have changed at 3rd Activity (if user do something in 3rd activity). And after 3rd activity we will come back to 2nd activity when values should be checked in loop.

Comment: And when they're checked in the loop, what values do you get there, and what values do you expect?

Comment: it was back 0. But problem was resolved by "project -> clean..." =) Thanks for help!